# jquery .each array json

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, jquery-mobile

Im new in here and this is my first post and i hope someone can help me.
im also new to jquery/jquery-mobile, API and JSON

im using aspx site, dont know if thats a help.

im making a search for movies on mobile with help from a jquery mobile, API and my JSON file is a array, but i cant finde out how i can get more then 1 movie out at one time.

so i hope someone can help me.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#Search_B").click(function() {

      $("#intro_h3").hide();

      var S_Value = $('#GetMovies').val();
      var url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + S_Value;
      var json = $.getJSON(url);

      console.log(url);


      $("#Search_B").each(json, function(i, value) {

        $('#movie').html('');
        $('#movie').append('<h2> Title: ' + value.Search[0].Title + ' </h2>');
        $('#movie').append('<h3> Year: ' + value.Search[0].Year + ' </h3>');
        $('#movie').append('<h3> Type: ' + value.Search[0].Type + ' </h3>');
        $('#movie').append('<a href=http://www.imdb.com/title/' + value.Search[0].imdbID + ' target="_blank"> <img src=' + movie.Search[0].Poster + ' /> </a>');
        $('#movie').append('<br><a href=http://www.imdb.com/title/' + value.Search[0].imdbID + ' target="_blank"> Imdb </a>');
      });

    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

      <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="header">
          <h1>Welcome to the online movie searcher</h1>
          <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#page1">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#page2">Options</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

          <!-- <input type="text" id="EnterMovie" /> -->
          <input type="search" id="GetMovies" />
          <input type="button" id="Search_B" value="Search" />

          <div id="movie"></div>


          <h3 id="intro_h3">Search for a movie up top!</h3>


        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
          <h1>My Footer</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of the changes made to the code work:

- You are using `$.html('')` to clear the `#movie` section inside the `$.each()` call. Instead you should do it only once outside the loop.
- `$('#movie')` is the jQuery function being executed with `'#movie'` as argument and it requires process time. You can *chain* the `$.append()` methods to save process' time.
- `$.getJSON(url, callback)` is an asynchronous method, your `json` variable will be available inside `callback` function only after the API has finished its work.
- `$.each(array, function(key, val) {})` will not work with a JSON object as array. The first argument must be the iterable `json.Search` instead.

Your final code should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#Search_B").click(function () {
    $("#intro_h3").hide();
    $('#movie').html('');

    var S_Value = $('#GetMovies').val();
    var url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + S_Value;

    $.getJSON(url, function waitAPIthen (json) {
        $.each(json.Search, function (key, item) {
          $('#movie')
            .append('<h2> Title: ' + item.Title + ' </h2>')
            .append('<h3> Year: ' + item.Year + ' </h3>')
            .append('<h3> Type: ' + item.Type + ' </h3>')
            .append('<a href=http://www.imdb.com/title/' + item.imdbID + ' target="_blank"> <img src=' + item.Poster + ' /> </a>')
            .append('<br><a href=http://www.imdb.com/title/' + item.imdbID + ' target="_blank"> Imdb </a>');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thx didnt know that :)
and i have also replaced value.Search[0] to value.Search[i], but it still dont work :/ But thx

Comment: The loop is being executed once or none?

Comment: none at all, like the button dont work. i can press it but nothing happens

Comment: Try `console.log(json);` before the `$.each()`, what is the result in your console? I updated my answer to use `json.value` instead...

Comment: Try my updated answer, does it throw any error in your console(F12) ?

Comment: i get http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=batman if im searching for batman.

i cant type console.log(json.value); outside .each() only valueof

Comment: The API returns a JSON which you named `json`. There is a property `Search`, which contains the iterable array. So it will look like: `$.each(json.Search, function(key, item) {  })`. See my updated answer

Comment: i got a error:
jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: b.apply is not a function
    at Function.each (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.each (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (Default.aspx:118)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4)
    at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4)
each @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
each @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ Default.aspx:118
dispatch @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4
r.handle @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4

Comment: Oh I see, it is asynchronous... my bad. I will update

Comment: Updated. What happens is simple: your code will not wait for the API, because it can spend much time to return your json, then `$.getJSON()` accepts a second argument, which holds a function to execute when the JSON is returned. That's it... I updated my answer :) ... Sorry any ugly wordings I'm not fluent

Comment: but now i dont get any thing but the 
title: undefined
Type: undefined
And so on

Comment: and i got this error: GET http://localhost:48475/undefined 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Have you copy-pasted my `$.each()` code? I just tested and it works here. I will double-check

Comment: i got it to work now :) i was missing the big S in search in each after json, im so dumb :)

I can not thank you enough :D

Comment: Glad to see it worked :) ... Basically all goes through `$.getJSON()` _(asynchronous call)_ and `$.each()` _(array and function(key, value))_ usage

Comment: You can [mark my answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/321253) if it worked to you

Comment: It makes me happy too :P